# Spring-MVC + Spring-websocket + @Cacheable don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-websocket

I have got a project on Spring-MVC and Spring-websockets and I try to plug cache on my service layer. These are my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
  "com.example"
})
@PropertySource("classpath:/configuration.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableCaching
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehcache() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCache = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    ehCache.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    ehCache.setShared(true);
    return ehCache;
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehcache().getObject());
  }

  //...different settings by mvc

 }
```

and my websocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/locations").withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4).maxPoolSize(10);
  }
}
```

I want to use `@Cacheable` annotation on my service layer:

```
@Service
public class StoreServiceImpl implements StoreService {

  private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(StoreServiceImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  private StoreRepository storeRepository;

  @Override
  @Cacheable("stores")
  public Store findById(String storeId) {
    return storeRepository.findById(storeId);
  }

  //... others methods

}
```

but if I have included annotation `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` then the cache doesn't work, because aop interceptors do not use it, so
if I haven't included <strike>`@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`</strike> then cache and AOP interceptors work well.

The documentation on the websocket I found this information:

> In some cases a controller may need to be decorated with an AOP proxy
>   at runtime. One example is if you choose to have `@Transactional`
>   annotations directly on the controller. When this is the case, for
>   controllers specifically, we recommend using class-based proxying.
>   This is typically the default choice with controllers. However if a
>   controller must implement an interface that is not a Spring Context
>   callback (e.g. `InitializingBean`, *Aware, etc), you may need to
>   explicitly configure class-based proxying. For example with
>   `<tx:annotation-driven />`, change to `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />`

I tried use `@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)`, but it didn't help.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: which Spring version are you using?

Comment: version 4.2.4 @BrianClozel

Comment: Then this may be linked with [SPR-14030](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14030). Does the same behavior happen with Spring 4.1.x?

Comment: I can't go to 4.1.x version, because Stomp broker @since 4.2 version, but SPR-14030 is very intresting information, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided this problem:
I changed mode in @EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) and it works.
I think it depends of the order initialization BeanPostProcessors